# How to filter a table based on data from another table

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

there are three tables:

```
class Course(models.Model):

 name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
 description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
 start_date = models.CharField(max_length=255)
 end_date = models.CharField(max_length=255)

 def get_count_student(self):

   count = CourseParticipant.objects.filter(course=self.id)
   return len(count)

 def __str__(self):
   return f'{self.name}'

class Student(models.Model):

 first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
 last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
 email = models.CharField(max_length=255)

 def __str__(self):
  return f'{self.first_name}'

class CourseParticipant(models.Model):

 course = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='course', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 student = models.ForeignKey(Student, related_name='student', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I want to get students who do not participate in specific courses, I fulfill the following request

```
potential = Student.objects.exclude(courseparticipants__course=pk)
```

where in pk I indicate the id of the course, in response I get:

*django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'courseparticipants' into field. Choices are: email, first_name, id, last_name, student*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `related_name` is the name that is used by the *related model's* reverse accessor and is also the default related query name. Hence when you write the following in `CourseParticipant`:

```
student = models.ForeignKey(Student, related_name='student', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

It means `Student` now will have a reverse accessor named `student` which can be used to access its related `CourseParticipant` instances. Looking at this you would realize that you have chosen an incorrect (at least semantically) value for the `related_name`. Hence with this related name your query should be:

```
potential = Student.objects.exclude(student__course=pk) # Very confusing, yes?
```

A better solution would be to change the related name to something more suitable:

```
student = models.ForeignKey(Student, related_name='course_participants', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now you can write your query as:

```
potential = Student.objects.exclude(course_participants__course=pk)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not specify `related_name` in `CourseParticipant` model it is set to `courseparticipant_set` by default, so your query should be:

```py
potential = Student.objects.exclude(courseparticipant_set__course=pk)
```

Comment: Student.objects.exclude(courseparticipant_set__course=pk) I still get an answer                                django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'courseparticipant_set' into field. Choices are: email, first_name, id, last_name, student

Comment: I do not know what to do